# Keep up to 3 decimals without doing any rounding

Tags: java, string, floating-point, double, bigdecimal

I have a double that I want to keep only 3 decimal places but *without* applying any rounding at all.
E.g. `92.36699` should be `92.366`
I tried the following:

```
DecimalFormat nf= new DecimalFormat("#0.000");  
String number = nf.format(originalNumber);
```

But this results in `92.367`
How can I do what I need?

Comment: You could use integer-division: `((originalNumber * 1000) / 1) / 1000.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't "no rounding", it's [`DOWN` rounding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#DOWN). Simply [set the roundingMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setRoundingMode(java.math.RoundingMode)).

```
DecimalFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#0.000");  
nf.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
String number = nf.format(originalNumber);
```

Note the difference between `FLOOR` and `DOWN` - only relevant for negative numbers. `FLOOR` rounds towards **negative infinity** therefore `-92.36699` would become "-92.367".

Comment: Truncation is properly done with `RoundingMode.DOWN` as `RoudingMode.FLOOR` always rounds towards negative infinity.

Comment: @paper1111 just adding a note on that. Fair point on which one to use by default.